# How to simulate touch with left mousebutton

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-xe4, firemonkey-fm3

I'm developing a Firemonkey Application wich should run on Windows with touchscreen. 
Because I have no touchscreen for my development system, I can't test the behavior of some controls. For example the panning in a TListbox doesn't work with the mouse-button. It only works if ssTouch in KeyState is set.
Is there a way to simulate the touch via the mouse?

Regards,
Michael

Answer (score 1):

Well, aside from the obvious answer (save up and get that touchscreen!), there are some solutions, but they might be a bit involved.

If I wanted to do this on PC, I would start by making a copy of the Firemonkey source code and including it in my project.

After checking to see that your 'local' copy of Firemonkey is compiling properly, you will have to edit this file: "FMX.Platform.Win.pas".  Open this file and then search for "ssTouch".

Inside of the WM_LBUTTONDOWN handler, there must be some logic which determines whether "ssTouch" is part of the KeyState or not.  Add it in yourself, and then the left button should be evaluated as a touch input.